# CURL to grab an XML file associated with this URL

Tags: php, xml, curl, domxpath

I am trying to use CURL to grab an XML file associated with this URL, then i am trying to parse the xml file using DOMxPath.

There are no output errors at this point it is just not displaying anything, i tried to catch some errors but i was unable to figure it out, any direction would be amazing.

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
    }

function tideTime() {


$ch = curl_init("http://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/noaatidepredictions/NOAATidesFacade.jsp?datatype=XML&Stationid=8721138");
$fp = fopen("8721138.xml", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($ch);
$domx = new DOMXPath($dom);
$entries = $domx->evaluate("//time");

$arr = array();
foreach ($entries as $entry) {

  $tide = $entry->nodeValue;

}
echo $tide;

}
?>
```

Comment: What do you get if you do `print_r($entries);`

Comment: You could remove the `@` before `$dom->loadHTML` to get some messages (or just `set_error_handler("var_dump");` beforehand if err display was disabled otherwise). Also you can't "catch" errors, just exceptions. And why are you passing the curl handle to it, not the file/content?

Comment: Shouldn't `@$dom->loadHTML($ch);` be `@$dom->loadHTML($fp);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youre trying to load the `curl` resource handle as the DOM which it is not. the curl functions either output directly or output to string.

```
$ch = curl_init("http://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/noaatidepredictions/NOAATidesFacade.jsp?datatype=XML&Stationid=8721138");
$fp = fopen("8721138.xml", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data);
// the rest of the code
```

Comment: When i do this, and i echo $data - it is not pulling any infromation from the XML file i am trying to get, it seems like it is just requesting something from the page and the page is throwing an error back and its grabbing the html from the error...

Answer (score 0):

it seems you try to catch some unavailable xpath, make sure you have `("//time");` in the xml file, are you sure that you grab is a xml file ? or you just put into xml ?

Comment: this is the URL that has the file i am trying to get. http://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/noaatidepredictions/NOAATidesFacade.jsp?Stationid=8721138

Comment: if you look at that page there is a button to the right that says XML - i tried to pull the path from that button and ended up with a really large url and that didnt work either, - you are probably right they are probably generating an xml file on the fly and thats why it has you download the xml file and doesnt just open in the browser when you click that link.... --- what method could i use to catch this generated xml?

Answer (score 0):

if we look at that page, it seems xml generated by javascript, look at the `http://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/noaatidepredictions/NOAATidesFacade.jsp?datatype=XML&Stationid=8721138&text=datafiles%2F8721138%2F09122011%2F877%2F&imagename=images/8721138/09122011/877/8721138_2011-12-10.gif&bdate=20111209&timelength=daily&timeZone=2&dataUnits=1&interval=&edate=20111210&StationName=Ponce Inlet, Halifax River&Stationid_=8721138&state=FL&primary=Subordinate&datum=MLLW&timeUnits=2&ReferenceStationName=GOVERNMENT CUT, MIAMI HARBOR ENTRANCE&HeightOffsetLow=*1.00&HeightOffsetHigh=* 1.18&TimeOffsetLow=33&TimeOffsetHigh=5&pageview=dayly&print_download=true&Threshold=&thresholdvalue=`

may be you can grab that